# if i pull down the screen from top to bottom through a gesture, a search box should open

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i am beginner to android i have to add a gesture to my listview. when i pull down it should open search box. can anyone help me how to do those gesture detection... i have implemented it in various other views... but i couldn't do for listView... i don't what going wrong... my search module code is`

```
  dataAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_items, itemList);
                lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                final EditText searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter_text);
               //searchBox.addTextChangedListener(this);
                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

             // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
                searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                        Log.d("Constants.TAG", "*** Search value changed: " + cs.toString());
                        CateringList.this.dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        //if(arg0.length()==0)
                       // {

                       // }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to detect overscroll

```
 protected void onOverScrolled (int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY)

Called by overScrollBy(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, boolean) to respond to the results of an over-scroll operation.
Parameters
scrollX     New X scroll value in pixels
scrollY     New Y scroll value in pixels
clampedX    True if scrollX was clamped to an over-scroll boundary
clampedY    True if scrollY was clamped to an over-scroll boundary
```

Decide a logic based on these parameters and hide and show a search box at the top of the list view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i need to implement that overscroll into my application..

Answer (score 0):

You can `setOnTouchListener` for listview. 
Simple code:

```
this.getListView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    lastY = ev.getRawY();
                } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    nowY = ev.getRawY();
                } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if ((nowY - lastY) > 0) {
                        //PULL_DOWN_EVENT, custom function here where you can show you search box view;
                    }
                    nowY = 0;
                    lastY = 0;
                }
                return false;
            }
          });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.But method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTouchListener(){}) i get this error message...any idea???

Comment: @DeepakD, can you support full code? View own setOnTouchListener method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener)

Comment: ,I tried implementing. but the problem is Touch action is not working. I tried onFling. its not working..